# nhibernate query without collections

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Risking to ask very basic question, but still, here it is.
When using query like this

```
List<User> users = session.Query<User>.ToList();
```

In debugging I see that besides user entity I'm fetched and Role collection and Photo collection.

My question is how can I select only User collection without child collections.

Thanks

Update:

```
public RoleMap()
{
   Table("Role");
   Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
   Map(x => ...
   References(x => x.User).Column("UserId");           
}
```

As far as I know lazy loading is turned on by default. Correct me If I anything doing wrong  here.

Comment: what do you debug? Are you checking the sql query?

Comment: I'm debugging line by line and in users collection I have loaded Collection of Roles by default.

Comment: Are you returning these results from a webservice?

Comment: @panjo: please check if my edited answer explain the behavior you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double check your generated sql.

Lazy load is on by default, so I think you are entering those collections in debuging on + sign to related collection and those should be load on demand clicking on that sign.

Please use nhibernate profiler to check generated sql.

Answer (score 4):

When you watch the collection on debug, you cause the data to be loaded from database using the proxy created by nhibernate. Check the generated sql query when you execute

```
 List<User> users = session.Query<User>.ToList();
```

you should only see `User` data, roles and photos shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Use Projections...

```
 ICriteria crit = Session.CreateCriteria<District>();

        crit.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
         .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("Description"), "Description"))
         .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("Active"), "Active"))
         .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id"))
         );
        crit.SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(District)));
        return crit.List<District>();
```

This hydrates the properties you're interested in, and ignores the others...good for cutting down on the amount of traffic over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lazy Loading: http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/lazy-loading-eager-loading.html

That means: NHibernate will only load these child (associations) when you really need them.